# How to clone Ubuntu Server for Raspberry Pi's

Tags: server, raspberrypi

I've seen the latest news that Ubuntu Server (plus a desktop added later) is a good match for the latest RPi-4 (with overclock trick). I would then need to get such an installation on many RPi's, but with all the proper customized software already set up (e.g., Emacs with an elaborate custom .emacs.d/, sqlite, gnuplot, Lubuntu desktop, etc), i.e., not just the base install from an .iso. So can I get an initial, say, 32gb SD card set up exactly as I want with all the additional packages I want, then create an iso of it? I'm guessing I need that initial install on the first machine to have no established user/password so users can then create their own, correct?

Comment: To narrow this down, you want to have a single custom disk image that you want to use across multiple Raspberry Pi 4 units?  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, get one machine loaded with exactly the software we need, then clone that machine to many others.